# When/where does the data aws_availability_zones is initialised or injected?

Tags: terraform

I am reading the terraform code here https://github.com/linuxacademy/content-terraform/blob/master/course/terraform-aws/networking/main.tf and here are the code I don't quite understand.

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

....

resource "aws_subnet" "tf_public_subnet" {
  count                   = 2
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.tf_vpc.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.public_cidrs[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"

  tags {
    Name = "tf_public_${count.index + 1}"
  }



}
```

I don't understand when the `data.aws_availability_zones` is populated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.aws_availability_zones` is data source, different from `resource` (the next code you pasted)

Please go through this url [terraform data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html) to understand how data sources work

If you don't understand how `data.aws_availability_zones` works, go through this url [Data Source: aws_availability_zones](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/availability_zones.html)

So from its `Attributes Reference`, we know it will help to get current account's availability zones.

```
zone_ids - A list of the Availability Zone IDs available to the account.
```

Its attribute `name` is alias of `zone_ids`, their outputs are same.